# Проблема с суперглобальной переменной $_SESSION

Tags: php

есть форма регистрации пользователя с таким кодом.

```
    <?php
session_start();
// Капча
$rand = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
$_SESSION["rand"] = $rand;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Название нашего сайта</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<form class="form" action="../database/signup.php" method="post">
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="first_name" required="required">
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Ваша фамилия" name="last_name" required="required">
    <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="Ваш email" name="email" required="required">
    <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="Пароль" name="password" required="required">
    <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="Подтвердите пароль" name="password_confirm" required="required">
    <?php
    echo "<h3>Проверочный код: </h3>" . "{$rand}";
    ?>
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Проверочный код" name="captcha" required="required">
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="btn_submit_register">Регистрация</button>
    <!--Блок для вывода сообщений-->
    <p class="msg">
        <?php
        echo  $_SESSION["msg"];
        unset($_SESSION["msg"]);
        ?>
    </p>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Эти данные идут в этот файл

```
<?php
session_start();
require "dbconect.php";

$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$password_confirm = $_POST["password_confirm"];
$captcha = $_POST["captcha"];

var_dump($_POST);

if (($password == $password_confirm) and ($captcha == $_SESSION["rand"])) {
    header("Location: ../www/form_auto.php");
} else {
    $_SESSION["msg"] = "Пароли не совпадают или неверно введена капча";
    header("Location: ../www/form_register.php");
}

?>
```

При разных паролях под формой должно выводиться сообщение об этом, но вместе этого пишет, что Undefined array key "msg" in.
Вот структура папок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что он должен писать, когда впервые показывает форму?

Comment: Как бы не удивительно после unset($_SESSION["msg"]) линии в блоке вывода сообщений ...

Comment: @splash58, да ты , прав.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, о каких линиях ты говоришь?